# After Successful Bootcamp Installation of Windows, Mac OS X is unaccessable

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, imac, windows

URGENT HELP NEEDED!

I have a Late-2014 iMac. Recently, I tried to Boot Camp it. However, It went horribly wrong and now I can't access Mac OS X. I am still able to access Windows though. Here's what happened:

I went to Boot Camp Assistant, and checked all the boxes, Create a Bootable USB, install Windows 10 Software, and Install Windows. I ran the process through correctly until It asked me to select the partition sizes. I set it to 700 GB Mac OS and 300 GB windows. However, after pressing enter, I pressed esc because I wanted it to be split equally. However, the process already started. So I force quit the Application and restarted the process. This time I gave Windows a little bitmore space. After that, everything went smoothly. I installed windows, installed a couple apps but when I tried to boot into Startup Manager (by holding Alt at startup) it didn't work. Then I tried to boot into Mac OS using the Boot Camp Manager via windows, but it replied with this:

[image: Could Not Locate The OS X Boot Volume]

Then I tried booting up Mac OS from Windows Advanced Startup Options, but that didn't work either. Whatever I tried, it just lead to windows. So then I tried to get into Mac OS Recovery using Command + R, but that didn't work so I tried using Alt + Command + R, but that didn't work either. I have absolutely no idea what to do whatsoever. Please Help Me!

[image: Disk Manager Windows]

EDIT: Using another computer, I installed Mac OS Catalina Install USB. Using This I Intend to use Recovery. HOWEVER, I cannot find a way to boot into it. Can anyone help me attempt to boot the USB from windows?

Comment: From the 100% Free Space listed for both partitions for Disk 0 and Disk 1, it looks like you may have initialized (erased) your Mac volumes. Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: No, I do not have a Time Machine Backup. However, After A little research, I have found that I can make a bootable Mac OS Recovery Drive. However, I will only use that as a last resort.

Comment: What if Restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Option (or Alt) ⌥ key on your keyboard during startup, do you get two drive option or only one for Windows ?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just immediately launches into Windows.

Comment: So I have installed a Mac OS Catalina Install USB but have no idea how to boot it. Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Opened up Windows in Advanced Startup Options, pressed boot from another drive, then pressed Cmd + Alt + R and was able to boot into Internet Recovery. Then I pressed continue to Mac OS and I was finally able to boot into Mac OS.